# Stop sidebar from moving down when the browser is resized

Tags: html, css

I just encountered with a strange problem.Though i haven't used any media queries on my site,the sidebar of my blog moves down when i resize my window like it's responsive but it's not.It is supposed to stay there as it is .
How do i overcome this problem  with css?

[My blog link](http://crystallax.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Please do not link to external sites. Try replicating your problem in a Fiddle.

Comment: How do i demonstrate a problem with my sidebar in a fiddle??

Comment: Why not? Just use the code on your site, and put them in a fiddle.

Comment: I'm a bit noob in coding so sorry about that.Next time ,i'll try my best..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a wrapper with a min-width attribute, since the total width of your site retracts and can no longer support your sidebar beside the content node.

```
div.wrapper { min-width:XXXpx; }


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar">
</div>
```

The wrappers `min-width` (or just `width`) must be wide enough to keep the sidebar and the content side by side. (Content width) + (sidebar width) = wrapper width.

Comment: And what are the css stylings for the class wrapper??

Comment: @AnzJoy I actually did if you would have read my answer. The wrappers `min-width` (or just `width`) must be wide enough to keep the sidebar and the content side by side. (Content width) + (sidebar width) = wrapper width. Also, I edited my answer to explain it futher.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use percentage(%),

```
<div style="width:25%;"></div>
```

Then it will re-size according to your browser window size.